# Как интегрировать сообщения от Slackbot на сайт?

Tags: php, api, slack

Имеется аккаунт на slackbot. Имеется бот, которые каждые 2 минуты посылает мне данные, в виде текста и ссылки, получив эти данные мне необходимо их вывести на сайте. Сайт на голом Html+PHP как это сделать ума не приложу. Инструкция у них на  английском, не разобрать. Знаю, что как-то через Апи делается, но как не догадываюсь. Может есть у кого примеры? Спасибо

Comment: Требуется пример кода и ссылка на API

Comment: @DaemonHK Получаю вот в таком виде https://cloud.mail.ru/public/3UYq/a8nJzx7c8 а ссылка на апи https://api.slack.com/web

Comment: @DaemonHK на просторах интернета нашел вот такой код, но он не пашет(  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269770/slack-api-attachments-not-showing

Comment: Давайте начнем с того, отправляются ли эти данные Вам на сайт вообще? Есть ли у вас парсер, который считывает эти данные?

Comment: К сожалению нету, но в другом месте спрашивал меня направили сюда https://api.slack.com/ и сюда написав 
It is very simple. Just follow one of these top tutorials: https://api.slack.com/tutorials    Вот пример данного размещения https://aviabay.ru/app/search.html

Comment: @DaemonHK если нужно то могу предоставить доступ к slackbot от куда получаю данные

Comment: @DaemonHK https://aviaciya.slack.com/messages/@slackbot/team/support/

Comment: Мой скайп - мой же ник маленькими буквами

Comment: @DaemonHK я сейчас на работе, могу на почту кинуть

Comment: @DaemonHK вот загрузил что у меня на входе https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zW56EIsAUu0&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63217/discussion-between-daemonhk-and-arcadiy).